# Keras create custom network with certain unconnected neurons

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am trying to create an autoencoder where a few inputs can affect the other inputs, but not the other way around. An example of this is given by the following picture. I looked into defining my own Keras layers, but don't know how to proceed. [image: Custom selectively connected neural network]

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work with my answer?

Comment: I made it work in tensorflow, but then realised that the functional API was what I was looking for like you said. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3):

I *believe* you can do this using the functional API and playing around with your input. Suppose you have the sets of input features (can be singleton sets) $a$,$b$,and $c$ for some $x$ in $X$. If you split your input into $X_a$, $X_b$, and $X_c$, where all elements in $x$ is transformed to include only features in $a$, you can theoretically build this model.

Here's a code snippet demonstrating this idea, given $X_a$, $X_b$, and $X_c$, and their corresponding shapes. You could widen this model by expanding the fully-connected layers (by increasing the variable set to 1 in the Dense calls). No promises on the code working off the bat: I've brushed over some details but this should give you a start on your problem.

```
input_A = Input(shape=shape_A)
input_B = Input(shape=shape_B)
input_C = Input(shape=shape_C)
A = Dense(1)(input_A)
A = Dense(1)(A) 
B = Merge([input_A, input_B, input_C], mode='concat')
B = Dense(1)(B) 
C = Merge([A,B],mode='concat)
C = Dense(1)(C)
B = Merge([A,B],mode='concat)
B = Dense(1)(B)
A = Dense(1)(A)
```

From here, if you want one output, you can call merge on $A$, $B$, and $C$ and then tack on a Dense (Fully-Connected) layer with, for example, a Softmax layer for multi-label classification.

Answer (score 0):

Keras does give a chance to add custom layers. I do not know about the previous versions but Keras 1.1.3 is flexible to do this. Have a look at this [link](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). This also contains a good example for a custom layer. Here, you can try to change the weight matrix according to your need. I'd also suggest you to try reading source code of some basic layers to understand it better.